# Is it necessary to multiply by sizeof( char ) when manipulating memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, sizeof

When using malloc and doing similar memory manipulation can I rely on sizeof( char ) being always 1?

For example I need to allocate memory for N elements of type `char`. Is multiplying by `sizeof( char )` necessary:

```
char* buffer = malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );
```

or can I rely on sizeof( char ) always being 1 and just skip the multiplication

```
char* buffer = malloc( N );
```

I understand completely that `sizeof` is evaluated during compilation and then the compiler might even compile out the multiplication and so the performance penalty will be minimal and most likely zero.

I'm asking mainly about code clarity and portability. Is this multiplication ever *necessary* for `char` type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While its not necessary, I consider it good practice to leave in the sizeof( char ) because it makes the code more readable and avoids the use of a magic number.  Also, if the code needs to be changed later so that instead of a char it's mallocing the size of something into a pointer for that object, it's easier to change the code than if you have just a "1".

Comment: This "ease of changing the code" argument is bull. `sizeof()` is 8 characters. Having to add it because someone didn't write `sizeof(char)` and then the type changed to `wchar_t` won't give anyone carpal tunnel, and if you're concerned this you should be using `sizeof *buf` anyway because it saves you even _less_ typing.

Comment: @ChrisLutz, I'm looking at the C11 standard and I don't see any clause the specifically says `sizeof(char)` is one. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types), it can be anything: _"for example, all types can be 64-bit"_. Could you please tell me where in the standard it says so?

Comment: @Shahbaz - 6.5.3.4 paragraph 4: "When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1." Thus it has always been, thus it will always be. The `char` is the "byte" of C. From the language perspective, it doesn't matter how many bits a `char` is, it is the smallest complete unit and all `sizeof` values are given in terms of `char`s rather than "bytes" (which don't properly exist in the C standard). If all types are 64-bit, `sizeof(char) == sizeof(short) == sizeof(int) == sizeof(long) == 1`, not 8.

Comment: @ChrisLutz, thanks, I was looking at where `char` and other types themselves are included. While we are on the subject, I had heard that they kept the size of `int` to 4 bytes because of old code instead of letting it grow as big as the CPU likes (like what happens with `long`). I had also heard that this happened in C99 where `long long` was introduced. Is that in anyway correct? If there are any restrictions on sizes of `int` and other types, where in the standard is that?

Comment: @Shahbaz - 5.2.4.2.1 lists the minimum sizes for all integer types. Basically, `signed char` must be able to represent at least all numbers between ±127, `signed short` and `signed int` between ±32767 (or ±(2^15 - 1) ), `signed long` between ±(2^31 - 1), and `signed long long` between ±(2^63 - 1). So `int` is only _required by the standard_ to be 2 bytes. In practice it's 4 bytes because "that's how it's always been" (even though it obviously hasn't). I think they keep `int` at 4 bytes in practice because otherwise what type would be 4 bytes? If you make it `short` then what type is 2 bytes?

Comment: @ChrisLutz, yes you are right. I thought they had standardized it so it would be reliable, but I was wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Shahbaz - If you need standardized, reliable sizes, use `stdint.h`, added in C99 for specifically that purpose.

Comment: @ChrisLutz, thanks. I am aware of that. However I was curious since I had been hearing a lot here on SO regarding these and I wanted to get my facts straight. Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: `buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * N);` is easy to write, no magic number and no need to match/edit should the pointer type of `buffer` change.

Answer (score 29):

By definition, sizeof(char) is always equal to 1. One byte is the size of character in C, whatever the numbers of bits in a byte there is (8 on common desktop CPU).

The typical example where one byte is not 8 bits is the [PDP-10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36-bit) and other old, mini-computer-like architectures with 9/36 bits bytes. But bytes which are not 2^N are becoming extremely uncommon I believe

Also, I think this is better style:

```
char* buf1;
double* buf2;

buf1 = malloc(sizeof(*buf1) * N);
buf2 = malloc(sizeof(*buf2) * N);
```

because it works whatever the pointer type is.

Comment: I thought that the definition of 1Byte = 8 bits. Do you have an example where this does not apply?

Comment: The definition of 1 byte is N bits, where N is machine dependant. Not all machines have 8 bits/byte (although there aren't that many these days that don't)

Comment: @AlexDrenea: Today, you will typically encounter only 8 bit bytes. But the definition of a byte varies and is not tied to today's architectures, because there were systems with 9 bit bytes and even 36 bit bytes. If you want to be sure, use the ISO term "octet" instead of byte.

Answer (score 14):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 no matter what type of memory manipulation you do.

However, `sizeof(TCHAR)` may vary depending upon your compiler options.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but doesn't the size of a character become larger in unicode situations?

Comment: @Shadow, no. The wide character type wchar_t is generally used instead of char in that case. The Microsoft-specific TCHAR business is a way to write code that can be compiled for either wide or narrow characters. It isn't clear whether that was a good idea or not.

Comment: @RBerteig: I would say it's clear that it's a bad idea. The only reason to use non-wide `char` strings on Windows is for the sake of having portable code that works the same on other more standards-conformant systems (POSIX). As soon as you write `TCHAR`, your code is already polluted with Windows-specific stuff and you might as well just use their wide functions and types directly. It's not like anybody **wants** their programs to break as soon as the user tries to open a filename with non-codepage characters in it.

Comment: @R., actually `TCHAR` was really a portability kludge to wean Windows 3.x  programmers off of 8-bit `char` by allowing carefully constructed code to compile without changes for Win16, Win32 in ASCII and Win32 in Unicode. Its use in the context of lots of Windows API calls is not going to affect your portability. **Don't** use it for the core of your application's processing, however, or you really are impacting portability. If you do avoid `TCHAR` with the API, please compile-time assert that `UNICODE` is defined and maybe write `MessageBoxW` not `MessageBox`, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I consider it kind of an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern). It signals that the programmer didn't quite know what he/she was doing, which immediately casts the rest of the code in dubious light.

Granted, it's not (quoting Wikipedia) "ineffective", but I do find it "far from optimal". It doesn't cost anything at run-time, but it clutters the code with needless junk, all the while signalling that someone thought it necessary.

Also, please note that the expression doesn't parse as a function-call: `sizeof` is not a function. You're not calling a function passing it the magical symbol `char`. You're applying the built-in unary prefix operator `sizeof` to an expression, and your expression is in this case a cast to the type `char`, which in C is written as `(char)`.

It's perfectly possible, and highly recommended whenever possible, to use `sizeof` on other expressions, it will then yield the size of the expression's value:

```
char a;
printf("A char's size is %u\n", (unsigned int) sizeof a);
```

This will print `1`, always, on all conforming C implementations.

I also heavily agree with David Cournapeau and consider repeating the type *name* in a `malloc()`-call to *also* be kind of an anti-pattern.

Instead of

```
char *str;

str = malloc(N * sizeof (char));
```

that many would write to allocate an N-character-capacity string buffer, I'd go with

```
char *str;

str = malloc(N * sizeof *str);
```

Or (for strings only) omit the `sizeof` as per above, but this of course is more general and works just as well for any type of pointer.

Comment: I disagree. If you omit it you (and anyone who reads your code) must remember that this is a special case and recognize it as such. That increases the cognitive burden. Sometimes more code is better.

Comment: Yes, sizeof is not a function - but to me it reads easier if you treat it like one. Unless you know of a case where the extra parentheses change the output?

Comment: @Michael Carman - It usually _is_ a special case, because you're often allocating and working with strings, whereas if you make an array of ints it could be for any purpose. We need to treat strings differently than arbitrary-typed arrays, and I find the lack of `sizeof(type)` in a `malloc()` to be a nice reminder of this.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary. See [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/sizeof_and_malloc.html) (for example).

**`sizeof(char)`** is defined by the C standard to always be **1** (byte). Note that because `sizeof` returns a number of *bytes* the number of bits per byte is irrelevant (and in practical terms is 8 anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Something else to keep in mind is that the compiler statically knows the value of sizeof (char) is 1 and it also knows that multiplying a number by a static 1 implies the multiplication doesn't need to be done; the compiler will optimize it out.  Concerns of performance shouldn't enter in to consideration on these grounds.

Answer (score 3):

From "New C standard. An economic and cultural commentary".

1. Statistics: 2.0% of sizeof are taken from `char` and 1.5% - from `unsigned char`. Page 1033 in 1.2 version of book.
2. page 1037.

> The number of bits in the representation of a character type is
>   irrelevant. By definition the number
>   of bytes in byte a character type is
>   one.
>
> Coding Guidelines Developers sometimes
>   associate a byte as always containing
>   eight bits. On hosts where the
>   character type is 16 bits, this can
>   lead to the incorrect assumption that
>   applying sizeof to a character type
>   will return the value 2.
>   These issues are discussed elsewhere.

Answer (score -4):

Using the sizeof(char) makes your code more readable and portable.

On x86, we all know that a character is 1 byte. But explicitly writing it down helps make your intentions clearer, which is always a good thing.

Also, what if your code gets put on some other platform where a character isn't 1 byte. What if a character was only 4 bits instead?

Agreed, it's not necessary, but it doesn't slow your run time down and it will pay off in that rare case you need to port your code to a different architecture.

Comment: That what I was asking about. Officially char is the smallest addressable chunk of memory which is not gauranteed to be 8 bits. The question is about whether the malloc and all other similar stuff works in term of chars, not 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Ahh ok, then yes, malloc works in terms of characters, not bytes.

malloc(1) will return 1 character size block of memory.

Comment: -1 your answer is factually incorrect. `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1. If a `char` is only 4 bits, then 4 bits is 1 byte on that platform, but `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 (byte), no matter how many bits it is. The issue you discuss is addressed by the `CHAR_BITS` macro.

Comment: The minimum possible value for `UCHAR_MAX` is 255; therefore `char` cannot be 4 bits.