# Allocating char array using malloc

Tags: c, char, malloc, sizeof, c99

Considering the following line:

```
char *p = malloc( sizeof(char) * ( len + 1 ) );
```

Why is sizeof(char) used? It's not necessary, is it? Or Is it just a matter of style?

What advantages does it have?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011806/is-it-necessary-to-multiply-by-sizeof-char-when-manipulating-memory though I disagree with the accepted answer there (I prefer to omit sizeof(char))

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it's a matter of style, because you'd expect `sizeof(char)` to always be one.

On the other hand, it's very much an idiom to use `sizeof(foo)` when doing a `malloc`, and most importantly it makes the code self documenting.

Also better for maintenance, perhaps.  If you were switching from `char` to `wchar`, you'd switch to

```
wchar *p = malloc( sizeof(wchar) * ( len + 1 ) );
```

without much thought.  Whereas converting the statement `char *p = malloc(  len + 1  );` would require more thought.  It's all about reducing mental overhead.

And as @Nyan suggests in a comment, you could also do

```
type *p = malloc( sizeof(*p) * ( len + 1 ) );
```

for zero-terminated strings and

```
type *p = malloc( sizeof(*p) * len ) );
```

for ordinary buffers.

Comment: Then why not use type *p = malloc( sizeof(*type) * (len+1) );
;)

Comment: @Nyan: Sure, that works too. I've never seen this before, but if I were still a working C programmer I would consider adopting your suggestion as an idiom ..  although the `len +1` part would only be for string-like objects.

Comment: Not only would you expect it to be 1 it's defined to be so.  One of the very few items whose size is explicitly defined.

Answer (score 2):

It serves to self-document the operation.  The language defines a char to be exactly one byte.  It doesn't specify how many *bits* are in that byte as some machines have 8, 12, 16, 19, or 30 bit minimum addressable units (or more).  But a char is always one byte.

Answer (score 2):

The specification dictates that chars are 1-byte, so it is strictly optional. I personally always include the `sizeof` for consistency purposes, but it doesn't matter