# String copy in C causing segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am trying to copy a string into another char pointer variable using strcpy function.But I always get segmentation fault.Here is my code.

```
/* strcat example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char str[100]="";
  char *pch3;
  strcpy(pch3,"Ravi");
  //strcat(str,pch3); //Segmnetation fault.
  puts(pch3);
  return 0;
}
```

If I do the same thing in this one I still get segmentation fault.

```
 else
      {
         misc_rec_cnt++;
         fp1=fopen("breast-cancer-wisconsin-miscellaneous.data","a");
         fprintf(fp1,"%s",line2);
         fclose(fp1);
         fp2=fopen("missingSCNs.data","a");
         pch2=strtok(line2,",");
         fprintf(fp2,"%s\n",pch2);
         fclose(fp2);

         //pch3=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(line3));
         pch3 = strtok(line3,",");
         while(pch3!=NULL)
         {
             if(strcmp(pch3,"?") == 0)
             {
                strcat(str1,"0");
                strcat(str1,",");
             }
             else
             {
                //strcat(str1,pch3);
                strcat(str1,",");
             }
             pch3 = strtok(NULL,",");
         }
         strlen1=strlen(str1);
         memcpy(str2,str1,strlen1-1);
         fp3=fopen("breast-cancer-wisconsin-miscellaneous-cleansed.data","a");
         fprintf(fp3,"%s\n",str2);
         fclose(fp3);
      }
```

Comment: No I am reading each and every line from a file and storing it in line3 buffer and using it in my code. But when I do strcat it always gives me seg fault.

Comment: Oh, wait, I just saw `pch3 = strtok(line3,",");`. You lose the `malloc`ed memory by that, and you shouldn't `malloc` `pch3` in that case.

Comment: But I see nothing in the second snippet that could cause a segfault. `line3` isn't long enough to cause an overrun of `str1` with the `strcat`s.

Comment: But the commented part is causing the problem. I really don't know why it's throwing error. This entire snippet code is inside a else condition which executes only 16 times.If I comment this snippet rest of my code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Which commented part? If you have `strcat(str1,pch3); strcat(str1,",");` in the `else` branch, then that would be enough to cause an overrun. Try with a larger `str1`, `char str1[200];` has enough space to accommodate the tokens of `line3` and the commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pch3` is an unallocated pointer, so you're writing data to a location that doesn't exist. Did you mean to assign it to `str`?

```
char str[100]="";
char *pch3;
pch3 = str;
strcpy(pch3,"Ravi");
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to allocate the space for `pch3` before you copy to it. Use `malloc` to create a char array large enough to accomodate the elements of your source string **before** you copy it. What you are currently doing is declaring a char pointer and not initialising it. Therefore the memory location that it points to could be anywhere - and that means that you should probably not be attempting to write to it - which is why you are getting the segfault. Using `malloc` will allow you to allocate a region of memory that you are safe to write to and this will solve your problem (assuming the call to `malloc` succeeds). You cannot just go writing data to random memory locations without getting segfaults and access violations.

Answer (score 3):

`pch3` is a char pointer, but it *doesn't have any storage associated with it* which is the cause of the problem. Call [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate some memory that the `pch3` pointer can point to and you should be ok.

At this point you have a char pointer that is uninitialized and just pointing somewhere unknown. So try this:

```
  pch3 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); /* 100 just as an example */
```

This [tutorial](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/282296/malloc-in-c-short-tutorial) might be helpful or this SO question: [Allocating char array using malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115564/allocating-char-array-using-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you first allocate memory before copying data to a random place.

```
strcpy(pch3=(char*)malloc(sizeof("Ravi")),"Ravi");
```

but better check if it didn't return null pointer.